# Flutter: Streambuilder stuck on ConnectionState.waiting (BLOC)

Tags: flutter

I am trying to load images into a StreamBuilder using BLOC, but the Streambuilder hangs indefinitely on ConnectionState.waiting. This only happens if the document doesn't exist - though I'm using an Initial Value (empty list), so I'm not sure why it still hangs?

**galleryBloc.dart:**

```
class GalleryBloc {
  final _multipleImageController = StreamController<List<File>>.broadcast();
  Stream<List<File>> get multipleImageStream => _multipleImageController.stream;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Load existing gallery images
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Future<void> getGalleryImages({DocumentReference docRef, List<File> tmpGalleryImages, Function callback}) async {
    try {
      DocumentSnapshot snap = await docRef.get();
      if (snap.exists) {
        for (var img in snap.data['gallery_images']) {
          File fetchedFile = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(img);
          tmpGalleryImages.add(fetchedFile);
        }
      }
     } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    callback(tmpGalleryImages);
    _multipleImageController.sink.add(tmpGalleryImages);
  }
```

**gallery.dart:**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  GalleryBloc _galleryBloc = GalleryBloc();

return StreamBuilder<List<File>>(
  stream: _galleryBloc.multipleImageStream,
  initialData: <File>[],
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) print(snapshot.connectionState);
    if (!snapshot.hasData) print("No Data");
    return Column(....
```

Comment: why do you use `docRef.get().then(...)` if your method is `async`? instead simply use `await docRef.get()`

Comment: Silly of me, thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the question with await